# Magento 2.3 installation problem

Tags: magento2.3.1, ubuntu

I have installed magento2.3.1 in example.com/test/ folder through commandline.Installed successfully. but when opening url in browser http://example.com/test/

it shows error 
[image]

in backend it shows error

[image]

Comment: Check your .htaccess file and also check the permissions for generation/ var/ and pub are correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any more information?

Have you ran the following, after upgrading?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

If you still get the error pages after that, what happens if you put:

```
die(__FILE__);
```

At the top of `index.php` or `pub/index.php` (depending on your setup)

Comment: var/www/html/example.com/public_html/test/index.php this  is the output

Comment: Nice one, so your requests are making it through, and php-fpm is working. If you take out the `die` and run something like: `curl -kI http://example.com/test/` what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

**Enable error reporting in magento and check exact error**

In app/bootstrap.php

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

uncomment  ini_set ( remove # ) #ini_set('display_errors', 1); to ini_set('display_errors', 1)

Or add this to index.php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And also enable developer mode.
First check current mode.
run this cmd

```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

it will so the current mode

if current mode is not developer than change mode to developer by this command

```
 php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

change permissions var/ pub/ generated/ forlder

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ genereted/
```

Comment: i have done all these.but its not working. In debug.log file it shows  Execution time: 127.85466098785 [] []
[2019-04-15 11:20:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://example.com/test/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}} []
[2019-04-15 11:20:35] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://example.com/test/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"SYSTEM_CONFIG"}} []

Comment: Hello then disable cache and flush cache

   php bin/magento cache:flush ,     php bin/magento cache:disable

I hope this will help